# How to plot EER (Equal Error Rate) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visualization, biometrics, confusion-matrix

I want to plot the performance of a 21 class classification. So I thought of plotting the EER (equal error rate).

I have computed the confusion matrix and been able to estimate the FPR and FNR for each class. And plotted both arrays. But my plot looks strange.

Is this the right way to plot FPR vs FNR in order to get an EER?

My code:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_oos, y_oos_pred)
cm_normalized = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] 

FP = cm.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(cm)  
FN = cm.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(cm)  
TP = np.diag(cm) 
TN = (len(y_oos) - (FP + FN + TP))

# False positive rate
FPR = FP/(FP+TN)

# False negative rate
FNR = FN/(TP+FN)


plt.plot(np.sort(FPR)) # Sorted in ascending order
plt.plot(np.sort(FNR)[::-1]) # Sorted in descending order


FPR array is ascending order:
[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.0125 0.0125 0.0125 0.0125 0.025  0.0375]


FNR array in descending order:
[ 0.75 0.5 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.    0. 0. 0.]
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703395/how-to-compute-plot-equal-error-rate-eer-from-far-frr-values-using-matlab) has a great explanation of how to plot EER, in the first answer.

The equal error rate is the error at the first point that the FNR and FPR curves intersect. In your data, they intersect at the seventh point, where both are equal to 0. That would be the EER. It sounds strange to get an error of zero, but that's coming from the data you're using, and maybe your data allows for zero FNR and FPR.

Comment: I do not know if I have computed correctly the FPR and the FNR from the confusion matrix. Maybe that is why they intersect in 0. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your `confusion_matrix` function doing?

Comment: From the confusion matrix I computed the FP (false positives), FN (false negatives), TP (true positives) and TN (true negatives). And using those values I computed the FPR and FNR; which are used to make the plot.

Comment: Your computation of FP/FN/TN/TP looks to be fine, and the FPR/FNR rates also look to be fine. Look at this [link](http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/) for more information.